# How to improve the resolution of Region image boundary or the density of boundary sampling points?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I want to draw the region between two function curves （Sqrt[x], x^2）：

```
Clear[R1, R2, R];
Plot[{Sqrt[x], x^2}, {x, -1, 2}, PlotRange -> { 0, 2}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {None, Automatic}}}]
```

If I use Region, the boundary is not smooth enough, what should I do?

```
R1 = ImplicitRegion[y^2 < x, {x, y}];
R2 = ImplicitRegion[y > x^2, {x, y}];
R = RegionIntersection[R1, R2]
Region[R, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}, Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> Automatic]
```

(Version: 11.3)

Comment: Use `RegionPlot[R, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}, Axes -> True]` for visualization, instead of just `Region`.

Comment: Thanks! @MarcoB

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved.

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.02}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}, Axes -> True, Ticks -> Automatic]
```